# compilation error in VS2010 Error 2259 and lnk 2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
class UserParamBase : public UserParamName
{
public:

inline UserParamBase() : m_pParent(NULL), m_bCreate(false), m_bLoad(false),  m_pParentWnd(NULL) {}
inline UserParamBase(const char* name) : UserParamName(name), m_pParent(NULL), m_bCreate(false),  m_pParentWnd(NULL) {}
inline UserParamBase(const UserParamBase&) : m_pParent(NULL), m_bCreate(false),  m_pParentWnd(NULL) {}      //define the copy constructor so as not to use the default
UserParamBase& operator=(const UserParamBase&) { return *this; }    //define the operator= so as not to use the default which would copy a pointer
virtual ~UserParamBase();   
void            attach(UserParamReg* page); 
void            PlaceCtrl(UserParamReg* page, CWnd* pParentWnd, const RECT & r, bool bLoad=true);
void            CreateCtrl()                {create(m_pParentWnd, m_rRegion);};
void            CloseCtrl()                 {close();};
virtual string& value(string& s)        = 0;
virtual bool    load(const string& s)   = 0;
virtual bool    readonly()               =0;        
virtual bool    readonly(bool bReadonly) =0;        
virtual SIZE    winSize()                =0;        
virtual bool    get()                    =0;        
virtual void    update()                 =0;        
virtual void    create(CWnd* pParentWnd,const RECT& rect) =0;   
virtual void    close()                                   =0;

inline bool     loadable() const { return m_bLoad; }

protected:
virtual void    set(bool bAsync=true);

private:

UserParamReg*       m_pParent;
bool                m_bCreate;
bool                m_bLoad;


protected:
RECT                m_rRegion;
CWnd *              m_pParentWnd;
CritSec             m_csWnd;
};

template <class T>
class UserParam : public UserParamB2<T>
{
public:
template <>
class UserParam< string > : public UserParamB2< string >
{
public:
static const LONG   labelHeight             = 16;
static const LONG   controlWidth            = 160;
static const LONG   controlHeightMultiline  = 60;
static const LONG   controlHeightSingleline = 18;
static const LONG   controlWidthFileButton  = 18;
static const bool   defaultMultiline        = true;
static const bool   defaultFileEdit         = false;
static const bool   defaultReadonly         = false;
static const bool   defaultAlignRight       = false;
enum {nIDFileButton=1000, nIDEdit};


inline UserParam() {}
inline UserParam(const type& t,const char* name=NULL)                   : UserParamB2<type>(t,name) {}
inline UserParam(const UserParam& t,const char* name=NULL)              : UserParamB2<type>(t,name) {}
template <class Y> inline UserParam(const Y& y,const char* name=NULL)   : UserParamB2<type>(y,name) {}

inline UserParam& operator=(const UserParam& c) { UserParamB2<type>::operator=(c); return *this; }

bool fileedit(bool bFileEdit) { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); return m_wnd.bFileEdit=bFileEdit; }

bool combobox(bool bComboBox=true) { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); return m_wnd.bComboBox=bComboBox; }

bool multiline()        { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); return m_wnd.bMultiline; }

bool multiline(bool bMultiline) { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); return m_wnd.bMultiline=bMultiline; }

void addtolist(string str) { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); m_wnd.vSelections.push_back(str); fillcombo();}

inline void alignRight(bool bAlignRight)    { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); m_wnd.bAlignRight = bAlignRight; }

inline bool alignRight(){ AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); return m_wnd.bAlignRight; }

bool readonly()  { AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true); return m_wnd.readonly; }

bool readonly(bool bReadonly)
{
    AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true);
    if(bReadonly==m_wnd.readonly) return m_wnd.readonly;
    if(m_wnd.wnd && m_wnd.wnd->GetSafeHwnd()) {
        if(bReadonly) m_wnd.wnd->PostMessage(WM_CANCELMODE);
        m_wnd.wnd->PostMessage(WM_ENABLE,(WPARAM)!bReadonly);
    }
    return m_wnd.readonly=bReadonly;
}

SIZE winSize() 
{
    SIZE p;
    p.cx=controlWidth;
    p.cy=labelHeight+((m_wnd.bMultiline && !m_wnd.bComboBox)? controlHeightMultiline : controlHeightSingleline);
    return p;
}

//get from control, validate data, set data member if valid;
//return true if data is valid, false otherwise
bool get()
{
    AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true);
    if(m_wnd.combobox && m_wnd.combobox->GetSafeHwnd()) {
        CString text;
        m_wnd.combobox->GetWindowText(text);
        this->assign((LPCSTR) text);

    } else if(m_wnd.wnd && m_wnd.wnd->GetSafeHwnd()) {

        //get value from control, set m_d
        char* psz=NULL;

        unsigned uSize = m_wnd.wnd->GetWindowTextLength()+1;
        try {
            psz=new char[uSize];
            m_wnd.wnd->GetWindowText(psz,uSize);
            s.assign(psz);
        }
        catch(...) {
            if(psz) delete [] psz;
            throw;
        }
        if(psz) delete [] psz;

        //remove '\r' chars; std::remove returns an iterator to the new .end() position
        //use s.erase(..) to erase from this new .end() position through then end of s
        s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(),s.end(),'\r'),s.end());
        this->assign(s);
    } 

    return true;
}
```

Error message is as:

```
c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparam.h(437): error C2259: 
'user_param::UserParamB2<std::string>' : cannot instantiate abstract class
 due to following members:   

 'bool user_param::UserParamBase::readonly(bool)' : is abstract
 c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(126) : see   
 declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::readonly'
 'bool user_param::UserParamBase::readonly(void)' : is abstract

 c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(125) : see 
 declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::readonly'
 'SIZE user_param::UserParamBase::winSize(void)' : is abstract

 c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(127) : see  
 declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::winSize'
 'bool user_param::UserParamBase::get(void)' : is abstract 

  c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(130) : see  
  declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::get'
  'void user_param::UserParamBase::update(void)' : is abstract

  c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(131) : see
  declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::update'
  'void user_param::UserParamBase::create(CWnd *,const RECT &)' : is abstract

  c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(132) : see
  declaration  of 'user_param::UserParamBase::create'
  'void user_param::UserParamBase::close(void)' : is abstract

  c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(133) : see 
  declaration  of 'user_param::UserParamBase::close'
```

When I try to overide the pure virtual function using override function, then there are no error, but at the end i get lots of linking errors lnk2001. Please help me to resolve this issue. Many thanks in advance. If I miss something or if something seems to be not clear please let me know. Although again with VS 2003 there is no such problem, this is happening in vs 2010.

Comment: Well, what's unclear wit the error messages? You don't override all pure-virtual functions, as such the class is still abstract and you can't instantiate it. Also, what is `UserParamB2`? And that inner class also looks suspicious. All in all, you may also want to take a look at [Boost.ProgramOptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options.html), atleast it seems like you try to accomplish something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class member functions are meant to be overrriden in the derived class. Their purpose is to declare an interface without providing its implementation. So when you see something like `virtual int foo() = 0;` in any class declaration it means that you have to make a derived class and provide a `foo()` implementation to be able to use this class:

```
class CBase {
public:
virtual int foo() = 0;
virtual double bar() = 0;
}

class CDerived : public CBase {
public:
virtual int foo();  //no more `= 0` here cause implementation is provided
virtual double bar();
};

int CDerived::foo()
{
     return 0;
}

double CDerived::bar()
{
     return 0.5;
}

int main()
{
    CBase b; //error - abstract class
    CDerived d; //ok
}
```

A compiler should give an error if you have `virtual int foo() = 0` in your CDerived and provide a function definition. The fact that VS2003 compiles such code looks like conformance issue.

**Edit**

You have more errors in your code.

For a class declared as:

```
class UserParamBase : public UserParamName
{
 /*...*/
virtual bool    readonly();
}
```

the function definition should be:

```
bool UserParamBase::readonly()
{
 /*...*/
}
```

It is strange that the code for readonly() and such was compiled successfully in your case. You defined those functions as globals (or inside namespace) and so they could not access protected class members like `m_csWnd`.

Comment: yes exactly. i too doubt about conformance issue..please tell me the specific way to get ride of this.

Comment: @user1107855 Just don't use `= 0` when you are declaring a virtual function which will have an implementation. See the code example in my answer.

Comment: @ Pavel, issue is still unfixed with linker error 2001..:(  i will post you the recent code how it looks like.

Comment: It is easy to deal with lnk2001: find the missing object (e.g. function the linker is refering to) in your code and look for anything wrong. Is function definition corresponds to its declaration in the class? is it defined in the correct namespace? The linker is looking for class members in `user_param` namespace, but I don't see a single reference to it in your code. Try to check namespace-related stuff, perhaps it will help

Comment: ya problem is fixed now,the function defination was not defined in correct namepace, :) tons of thanks for helping me :)